How to connect Scarlett 2i4 interface with pipewire
I am running Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 on a Dell desktop computer.  I would like to use a Scarlett 2i4 as my sound card.  If I plug the Scarlett in (via USB) to the computer and run pw-cli list-objects | grep alsa_input I get node.name = "alsa_input.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i4_USB-00.analog-stereo" as the output.  However, the Scarlett does not show up in the list of available audio devices when looking at Settings>Audio.  How do I get the Scarlett into the list of devices, so that I can output the sound?
